# Single Combat vs Shroud

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If Player A had a creature with shroud on the battlefield, and Player B cast [Single Combat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=single%20combat), would Player A be able to choose the shrouded creature as the creature they keep?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can choose a shrouded permanent. And if a shrouded permanent isn't chosen, it must be sacrificed.

---

> 702.18a Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”

When a rule or ability uses a word with a rule meaning, it only refers to that specific meaning. Target is such a word.

Only the following target:

- Spells and abilities on the stack that use the word "target".
- Aura spells (since the rule text for these uses the word "target").

Keep in mind that certain keyword abilities represent abilities that use the word target (e.g. Equip).

[Single Combat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSingle%20Combat%5d) doesn't target, so it's unaffected by Shroud.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Player A may choose to keep - or sacrifice - the creature with Shroud.

Shroud is defined in [CR 702.18](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Shroud):

> Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “This permanent or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”

"Target" has a very particular meaning in MTG.  An entity is only a "target" when the card or ability specifically uses the word "target".  Since Single Combat doesn't target anything, Shroud has no bearing on how this card plays out.

Comment: Aura spells also target